# How to know aperture when mounting smartphone on telescope?

Tags: photography

I have a telescope with a 130mm aperture and a Samsung Galaxy S10, which I mount to my  telescope and use to take pictures. When considering the total aperture, how would I calculate the combination of the two different apertures?

Comment: "I have a *telescope with a 130mm aperture* and a Samsung Galaxy S10..." The telescope has the 130mm aperture, not the phone.